# how to remove light and shadow By GPUImage filter

Tags: objective-c, ios, gpuimage

I want to convert a image which take from camera to black and white and print it.This image is just take from document or paper.
so I use the follow code:

```
{

GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:  srcImg ];            

GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter *stillImageFilter = [[GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter alloc] init];
stillImageFilter.blurSize = 1;


[stillImageSource addTarget:stillImageFilter];
[stillImageSource processImage];

UIImage *outputImg = [stillImageFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
[stillImageSource release];
[stillImageFilter release];


}
```

but the output image has so many sawtooth, because the image is full binarization , and  it just need partial binarization. so I convert the source image to grayscale first and then  give the max contrast , the image is looks so good,but the light and shadow can not remove .
Any ideas,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try to apply GPUImageLuminanceThresholdFilter after GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter, and play with 'blurSize' property

```
-(UIImage *)doBinarize:(UIImage *)sourceImage
{

 GPUImagePicture *imageSource = sourceImage;

    GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter *stillImageFilter = [[GPUImageAdaptiveThresholdFilter alloc] init];
    stillImageFilter.blurRadiusInPixels = 8.0;//play with it

    GPUImageLuminanceThresholdFilter *stillImageFilter2 = [[GPUImageLuminanceThresholdFilter alloc] init];
    stillImageFilter2.threshold = 0.5f;//
    [stillImageFilter addFilter:stillImageFilter2];

    [stillImageFilter prepareForImageCapture];



    [imageSource addTarget:stillImageFilter];

    [imageSource processImage];


    UIImage *retImage = [stillImageFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];

    [imageSource removeAllTargets];

    return retImage;
}
```